# Is it a good idea to hash a Python class?

Tags: python, class, inheritance, hash, dictionary

For example, suppose I do this:

```
>>> class foo(object):
...     pass
... 
>>> class bar(foo):
...     pass
... 
>>> some_dict = { foo : 'foo',
... bar : 'bar'}
>>> 
>>> some_dict[bar]
'bar'
>>> some_dict[foo]
'foo'
>>> hash(bar)
165007700
>>> id(bar)
165007700
```

Based on that, it looks like the class is getting hashed as its id number. Therefore, there shouldn't be any danger of worrying about, say, a `bar` hashing as either a `foo` or a `bar` or hash values changing if I mutate the class.

Is this behavior reliable, or are there any gotchas here?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes, any object that doesn't implement a `__hash__()` function will return its id when hashed.  From [Python Language Reference: Data Model - Basic Customization](http://docs.python.org/reference/datamodel.html#object.__hash__):

> User-defined classes have `__cmp__()` and `__hash__()` methods by default; with them, all objects compare unequal (except with themselves) and `x.__hash__()` returns `id(x)`.

However, if you're looking to have a unique identifier, use `id` to be clear about your intent.  A hash of an object should be a combination of the hashes of its components.  See the above link for more details.

Comment: Any class whose *metaclass* doesn't have a __hash__() function.

Comment: It should be noted that although this is in the "what's new for Python 2.6" page, this behavior seems to work for me under python 2.4.

Comment: @Jason I changed the reference to the general documentation.

Comment: One thing that someone from work added:  it's important never to persist a dictionary that uses id in this manner.  The id is the memory address of the object, and it is only valid for the current process.

Comment: This answer is outdated.  `x.__hash__()` no longer returns `id(x)`

Answer (score 7):

Classes have default implementations of `__eq__` and `__hash__` that use `id()` to make comparisons and compute hash values, respectively. That is, they compare by identity. The primary rule for implementing `__hash__` methods is that if two objects compare equal to each other, they must also have the same hash value. Hash values can be seen as just an optimization used by dicts and sets to do find equal objects faster. Consequently, if you change `__eq__` to do a different kind of equality testing, you must also change your `__hash__` implementation to agree with that choice.

Classes that use identity for comparisons can be freely mutated and used in dicts and sets because their identity never changes. Classes that implement `__eq__` to compare by value and allow mutation of their values cannot be used in hash collections.